# Unable to retrieve instance of Object from bean

Tags: java, spring

I have defined `shipmentProperties.xml` file as:

```xml
<bean id = "shipmentProperties" class = "com.amazon.tfs.utils.Record" scope="prototype">
    <constructor-arg type = "java.lang.String" value = "shipmentProperties" />
    <property name = "schema">
        <map>
            <entry key = "shipmentProperty" value = "com.abc.xyz.data.types.ShipmentProperty" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

at some other place I tried to retrieve it by using

```java
myproperties = (Record) ApplicationBean.staticGetNonNullable("shipmentProperties");

if (myproperties == null) {
    logger.info("It is pkgGTSDataCreationSstage and shipmentProperties can not be retrieved from bean");
}
```

```java
ShipmentProperty prop = (ShipmentProperty) myproperties.get(shipmentProperty);

if (prop == null) {
    logger.info("Object of class shipmentProperties can not be retrieved from bean");
}
```

Now the problem is the output which is printed is Object of class `shipmentProperties` can not be retrieved from bean.

I didn't understand why it is not getting instantiated? Can somebody suggest me why this problem occurred?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ShipmentProperty` needs to be marked as a bean as well since the shipmentProperties bean depends on it. Also, I assume the `ShipmentProperty` class has getters within it?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<entry key = "shipmentProperty">
    <bean class="com.abc.xyz.data.types.ShipmentProperty" />
</entry>
```

assuming `ShipmentProperty` constructor takes no argument.